# Operation can only be performed on rows that belong to a DataGridView control?

Tags: .net, datagridview, objectdatasource

it happens when i change the DataSource.
i have checked everything(stack traces, all exception information, datasources, grids, all the threads, etc) i have also write lots of diagnostic code(+3000 line)
it seems to be a virus,  it is going to destroy everything in my app.
all grids are going to have the very same error.(while i have not changed any of the code).wtf  .

it makes my datagridviews to have an red X on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red X is .net's way of showing that an error occured in the drawing of the control code.

See these articles [1](http://www.sturmnet.org/blog/2005/03/23/red-x), [2](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/winform-data-binding/275/Big-Red-X-on-DataGrid), [3](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/fdd94896-80e9-4e91-9ed5-0348bf2633a9) for some hints on the possible causes/what you can do about it (if those links don't help googleing *"datagridviews have an red X"* brings up a lot of reading material).